# Django3 Paginator with function based view

Tags: python, django

```
class ProductList(ListView):
  model = Product
  paginate_by = 8

def company_page(request, slug):
  ...
  product_list = Product.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('-pk')

  paginator = Paginator(product_list, 4)
  page_number = request.GET.get('page')
  page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

  return render(request, 'product/product_list.html', {
    ...,
    'product_list': product_list,
    'page_obj': page_obj
  })
```

views.py

```
    <nav aria-label="Pagination">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center my-5">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <li class="page-item mx-auto lead">
                            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{page_obj.previous_page_number}}" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                            Newer</a>
                    </li>
             {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                            <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                            Newer</a>
                    </li>
             {% endif %}
             {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <li class="page-item mx-auto lead">
                            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}">
                            Older</a>
                    </li>
              {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled mx-auto lead">
                            <a class="page-link" href="#!">
                            Older</a>
                    </li>
              {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

product_list.html

I added pagination on ProductList view with `paginated_by` and imported Paginator to make other pages using a function view but it's only paginated on ProductList view and doesn't work on company_page view. The Newer & Older buttons work but the page keeps showing every product_list objects. How can I make it work on all pages?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`views.py`

```py
# other views ...

def company_page(request, slug):
  product_list = Product.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('-pk')

  page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
  paginator = Paginator(product_list, 4)

  try:
      Products = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      Products = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      Products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

  context = {'Products': Products}
  return render(request, 'product/product_list.html', context)
```

`product_list.html`

```html
<nav aria-label="Pagination">
{% if Products.has_other_pages %}
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-center my-5">
          {% if Products.has_previous %}
                  <li class="page-item mx-auto lead">
                          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ Products.previous_page_number }}" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                          Previous</a>
                  </li>
           {% else %}
                  <li class="page-item disabled">
                          <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                          Previous</a>
                  </li>
           {% endif %}
           {% for i in Products.paginator.page_range %}
               {% if Products.number == i %}
                  <li class="page-item mx-auto lead">
                          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">
                          {{ i }}</a>
                  </li>
               {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% if Products.has_next %}

                  <li class="page-item mx-auto lead">
                          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ Products.next_page_number }}">
                          Next</a>
                  </li>
            {% else %}
                  <li class="page-item disabled mx-auto lead">
                          <a class="page-link" href="#!">
                          Next</a>
                  </li>
            {% endif %}
      </ul>
  {% endif %}

  </nav>
```